# Split string on space (but not all..?)

Tags: go

Here I have a mock function that takes a single argument of multiple words in a single string, e.g. `"hello1 hello2 hello3 hello4 hello5 hello6 hello7"` etc.

The function will first do a match to see if the word `content` is in the string it received and then continue to split the string into arguments. If not matched with `content` then do something else.

My `dosomething` function is handling this data with the expectance of 5 arguments.

My question now is, how can I split these by delimiter *space* but everything that comes after `hello5` should be part of `arg5` below.

There is currently no way for me to know exactly how many arguments that are going to come in with `mystring`, hence concatenating fixed arguments will not work, it needs to be dynamic (is my assumption).

I hope this makes sense

```golang
func testing(mystring) {
    matched, err := regexp.MatchString(`content`, mystring)
    if err != nil { panic() }
    if matched {
        r := regexp.MustCompile("[^\\s]+")
        arguments := r.FindAllString(clientRequest, -1)
        arg1 := string(arguments[1])
        arg2 := string(arguments[2])
        arg3 := string(arguments[3])
        arg4 := string(arguments[4])
        arg5 := string(arguments[5])
        dosomething(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
    } else {
        log.Println("Not matched")
    }
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strings.SplitN](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitN) does exactly what you want.

Here is a small demo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", strings.SplitN("a b c d e f g", " ", 5))
}
```

Output:

```
["a" "b" "c" "d" "e f g"]
```

I also suggest adding an additional `if` statement to check that `strings.SplitN` returns a slice of the correct length.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. If I had only read the manual :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you're searching for a word and not a regex pattern, you can use this:

```
exists := strings.Index(str, "content")
```

This will return the first index of occurrence of `content`, or return `-1` if not found. If you do find a match, you can split the string till found `index-1`.

Here's a sample on playground to help you:
https://play.golang.org/p/QT39T6hStul

Comment: Thanks Rajvir, I’ll try that instead of the regex

Comment: Sure. Give me a thumbs up if it helped you :)